# JQuery input radio only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with JQuery, I have 2 sets of radio inputs, one for selecting the payment method and one for shipment. If I selected payment on pick up I want my second radio, the shipment to say pick up as well. This works fine until I change the second radio, after that it won't work.

So basically, after changing the shipment the shipment won't change automatically any more when changing the payment method.

```
$("input:radio[name=paymentMethod]").change(function() {
        if($(this+':checked').val()=='pickUp'){
            $('input:radio[name=deliveryMethod]').filter('[value=pickUp]').attr('checked', true);
            $('input:radio[name=deliveryMethod]').filter('[value=UPS]').attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: could you please post the relevant html?

Comment: It comes down to this (without the table structure)

<pre><code><input type="radio" checked="checked" id="pm_ideal" value="ideal" name="paymentMethod">
<input type="radio" id="pm_paypal" value="paypal" name="paymentMethod">
<input type="radio" id="pm_moneytransfer" value="moneytransfer" name="paymentMethod">
<input type="radio" id="pm_pickUp" value="pickUp" name="paymentMethod">
   

<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="UPS" name="deliveryMethod"> Delivery by UPS
<input type="radio" value="pickUp" name="deliveryMethod" checked="checked"> Pick up</code></pre>

Comment: your html is missing the names and closing the inputs, probably is related to the way it was pasted. Related to your problem, you would like the pickUp (delivery) to be checked unless you select UPS at the payment? and revert (check pickup at the delivery) if you select any other payment method?

Comment: it doesn't have to be reverted, you can pick up your order if you paid with paypal, but you can't select pay on pickup when you want to let your order be shipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "block" the choice of UPS delivery whenever the user selects the pickup payment method, I recommend disabling the UPS delivery method (and then re-enabling it if something else is selected), like this:

```
$("input:radio[name=paymentMethod]").change(function() {
    if ($('input:radio[name=paymentMethod]:checked').val() == 'pickUp') {
        $('input:radio[name=deliveryMethod]').filter('[value=pickUp]').attr('checked', true);
        $('input:radio[name=deliveryMethod]').filter('[value=UPS]').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('input:radio[name=deliveryMethod]').filter('[value=UPS]').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

**Fiddle**:
http://jsfiddle.net/zvcbz/

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a jQuery object, *not* a string. You cannot add them together. At least use the code below:

```
$("input:radio[name=paymentMethod]").change(function() {
        if($('input:radio[name=paymentMethod]:checked').val()=='pickUp'){
            $('input:radio[name=deliveryMethod]').filter('[value=pickUp]').attr('checked', true);
            $('input:radio[name=deliveryMethod]').filter('[value=UPS]').attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
```